# Function (..) throws 'eval is evil' message

Tags: javascript, eval, jslint

I'm not using eval, and I'm not sure what the problem is that Crockford has with the following. Is there a better approach to solve the following problem or is this just something I need to ignore (I prefer to perfect/improve my solutions if there is areas for improvement).

I'm using some pixel tracking stuff and in this case a client has bound a JS function to the `onclick` property of an HTML image tag which redirects off the site. I need to track the clicks reliably without running into race conditions with multiples of event listeners on the image. The strategy is to override the event at run time, copying and running it in my own function. Note this is being applied to a site I do not control and cannot change. So the solution looks something like:

```
...
func = Function(img.attr('onclick'));
...
img.attr('onclick', '');
... //some custom tracking code
func.call(this);
```

and the JSLint checker throws the `eval is evil` error.

Is there a better way to avoid race conditions for multiple events around `href` actions?

Comment: Seems like you just need to trigger the onclick event handler if it contains javascript code. img.onclick(); or  img.onclick.call();

Comment: @gillesc technically by that point it's a _property_ and not an _attribute_.

Comment: an event handler actually, but thanks for pointing out that it wasn't an attribute so I could correct it properly.

Comment: @gillesc `img.onclick` is a property, its _value_ is a handler.

Comment: Note that if the event handler is added through addEventListener instead of an `onclick="…"` attribute in HTML or an `.onclick=function(){…}`  property in JavaScript you will not be able to intercept or wrap it.

Comment: @gillesc - this doesn't address the race condition introduced by having multiple click or onclick events on the same image

Comment: @Phrogz that is true, but it's not a concern in my client's case. It is hard-coded in the HTML element.

Comment: There is no "race condition"; event handlers are invoked in a specific and well-defined order. If you hard set the onclick property it will replace any previous onclick handler. (This is not the same as adding multiple event listeners for a `click` event.)

Comment: @Phrogz if i "hard set" the property without keeping a copy of the original, i'll override and break the intended redirect. rule #1 of analytics is don't break existing user functionality. i've got to complete my tracking call and then initiate the originally defined code, all through client-side JS.

Comment: See my answer for how to do this without eval.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're implicitly using `eval` because you're asking for the callback function *as it was specified as an attribute in the HTML as a string* and then constructing a `Function` with it.

Just use the `img.onclick` *property* instead, and you will directly obtain the function that the browser built from the attribute that you can then `.call`:

```
var func = img.onclick; // access already compiled function
img.onclick = null;     // property change updates the attribute too

... // some custom tracking code

func.call(img, ev);     // call the original function
```

or better yet:

```
(function(el) {
    var old = el.onclick;
    el.onclick = function() {
        // do my stuff
        ..
        // invoke the old handler with the same parameters
        old.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})(img);
```

The advantage of this latter method are two fold:

1. it creates no new global variables - everything is hidden inside the anonymous closure
2. It ensures that the original handler is called with the exact same parameters as are supplied to your replacement function

Comment: I am stripping the `onclick` after copying it, so it's no longer a property of the image. Note that I mentioned that I call the function from inside my own code later on. If I leave it there, I can't guarantee that my tracking code completes before the redirect cuts it off

Comment: @patrickgamer so copy its (function reference) property value, not the original attribute text.

Comment: I've been bouncing back and forth between yours and Phrogz posts. I never really considered the differences between copying the attribute as a function and copying the property of the element. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
var oldClick = myImg.onclick;
myImg.onclick = function(evt){ 
  // Put you own code here
  return oldClick.call( this, evt );
};
```

Comment: ah, i see what you're saying now. Is this no longer going to throw the JSLint error?